# Бесплатный VDS хостинг

Tags: vds

Подскажите **нормальный** vds хостинг с бесплатным пробным  периодом. 
P.S нормальный - значит без использования банковских карт и подобного.

Comment: `нормальный - значит без использования банковских карт и подобного` ээээ)))

Comment: Биткоины что ли?)

Comment: @andreymal нет. Просто бесплатно. Нужно проверить работоспособность скрипта. Для этого нужен именно vds

Comment: А для проверки скрипта чем не годится, например, домашний компьютер?

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что он не соответствует тематике StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть сайт https://poiskvps.ru/ я там обычно себе нахожу то что мне нужно. Там можете указать удобный способ оплаты (не банковская карта) и другие параметры. Насчет пробного периода не знаю, но я там находил варианты совсем за копейки, типа на неделю за 100р.

Comment: Это грабеж. 12 руб./ мес вот норм https://www.host-food.ru